# Visibility binding on grid not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am trying to bind the visibility of grid but unable to do so.

```
//ViewModel Class
 private Visibility _isVisiblePane = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility isVisiblePane { 
            get
            {
                return _isVisiblePane;
            }
            set
            {

                _isVisiblePane = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => "isVisiblePane");
            }
        }
//xaml code
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=isVisiblePane}">
....My Content....
</Grid>
```

While debugging, the program sets the value to hidden but when i change the visibility of _isVisiblePane, it doesn't update visibility in GUI(grid remains hidden while _isVisiblePane value is Visible).

```
//in some function => on button click, value of _isVisiblePane updates to Visible but grid remains hidden.
     isVisiblePane = isLastActiveDoc() == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
```

Error! on RaisePropertyChanged("isVisiblePane") line. seems like there is no property with this name
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll but was not handled in user code"

PS: I have tried IValueConverter method with bool too. and still not figuring out whats the problem. Any help?

Comment: Yes, I am updating isVisiblePane

Comment: You need to set Binding element or data context. Thus change Visibility={Binding Path=isVisiblePane, Source=ViewModel}. Also, make sure that your class implements INotifyProperyChanged interace or move the property to a DependencyProperty if it's a UI class.

Comment: Are you seeing any red binding errors in the output window when the application runs?

Comment: If the ViewModel is in the DataContext and the Binding errors are not there, check if your ViewModel implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (maybe you only declared the event?)

Comment: I have updated the question...Error on RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: @BradleyUffner, There is no error in output window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Make sure that your ViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
- Make sure that RaisePropertyChanged which eventually calls PropertyChanged in the proper thread context if your view is also your UI.

  ```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(String info)
  {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)            
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));            
  }
  ```
- Make sure that the Grid either has your VM as it's data context or specify the proper Source for your binding.
- Make sure that RaisePropertyChanged has anything bound to it via

  if(RaisePropertyChanged != null)
          RaisePropertyChanged (....)

Comment: mostly, you first box the event to a var and then fire that event if it's not null `var local = PropertyChanged; if (local != null) local.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);`

Comment: You know, you are awesome! :D
Yes, my viewmodel wasn't implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I thought its the headache of Prism not of MVVM-Light.

Comment: @SaadAbdullah, `INotifyPropertyChanged`is a "headache" of WPF itself. :)

Comment: Yeah! time to improve my WPF concepts :P

Comment: I forgot to set datacontext!!!

Answer (score 6):

Not really answering, but:

- IMHO, you shouldn't have Visibility enums in your ViewModels. See, ViewModels should be agnostic of the view technology itself (realize, for instance, that INotifyPropertyChanged isn't part of the WPF libraries). So bind, instead, to a boolean and use a [converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Puiblic properties in .NET usually follows Pascal Casing, so, I suggest altering `isVisiblePane` to `IsPaneVisible`.
- Double check your view's DataContext.
- Run the project in debug mode and watch the console for messages concerning binding.

Comment: I have rename isVisiblePane => IsPaneVisible, nothing happens. No console message in output window

Comment: Thanks! In my case, it was the DataContext: `<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedObject}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedObject, Converter={StaticResource nullToHiddenConverter}}" >` This is wrong, since it would evaluate to `SelectedObject.SelectedObject`. Therefore, the following is the correct binding: `Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nullToHiddenConverter}}"`

Comment: If you are clueless, also check your converter. Maybe some logic is false there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Very late but everyone keeps suggestions to use a converter.  Good suggestion but still requires the use of more code behind.  You can use a data trigger as part of the style for your UI element and change visibility based on value of the bool in your model.
```

I.e.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyBoolValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is an underrated  answer. I would only recommend adding an additional trigger for when the value goes to false. Without it, the grid will always be visible, if the value ever gets set to true.